# Python urllib.request shows RemoteDisconnected error with OpenElevation API

Tags: python-3.x, api, urllib

I have an application (written in PyQt5) that returns x, y, and elevation of a location. When the user fills up the x, y, and hits **getz** button, the app calls the function below:

```
def getz(self, i):
    """calculates the elevation"""
    import urllib
    url = "https://api.open-elevation.com/api/v1/lookup"
    x = self.lineEditX.text()
    y = self.lineEditY.text()
    url = url + "\?locations\={},{}".format(x, y)
    print(url)
    if i is "pushButtonSiteZ":
        response = urllib.request.Request(url)
        fp= urllib.request.urlopen(response)
        print('response is '+ response)
        self.lineEditSiteZ.setText(fp)
```

according to [Open Elevation](https://github.com/Jorl17/open-elevation/blob/master/docs/api.md#request) guide, it says that you have to make requests in the form of:

```
curl https://api.open-elevation.com/api/v1/lookup\?locations\=50.3354,10.4567
```

in order to get elevation data as a JSON object. But in my case it returns an error saying:

```
raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"

RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
```

and nothing happens. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other way than to create a loop (try until the response is ok). Because the Open Elevation API's handling of so many responses is still problematic. But the following piece of code works after a possibly long delay:

```
def getz(self, i):
    import json
    import requests
    url = "https://api.open-elevation.com/api/v1/lookup"
    """calculates the elevation"""
    if i is 'pushButtonSiteZ':
        x = self.lineEditSiteX.text()
        y = self.lineEditSiteY.text()
        param = url + '?locations={},{}'.format(x,y)
        print(param)
        while True:
            try:
                response = requests.get(param)
                print(response.status_code)
                if str(response.status_code) == '200':
                    r = response.text
                    r = json.loads(r)
                    out = r['results'][0]['elevation']
                    print(out)
                    self.lineEditSiteZ.setText(str(out))
                    cal_rng(self)
                    break
            except ConnectionError:
                continue
            except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
                continue
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                continue
            except requests.exceptions.SSLError:
                continue
            except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
                continue
```